# Process in Linux Kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, archlinux

In user-space we can create a process by executing program or calling fork inside a program, Kernel will create process descriptor(task_struct) for each user-space process.

In kernel space is there any any concept called process, if so how they will be created?

As per my understanding kernel threads will be created in kernel space using `kernel_thread()` etc, `kernel_thread()` is internally calling `do_fork()`, so kernel threads also represented using `task_struct`?

If both user-space process and kernel space threads are represented using `task_struct`, then how scheduler will schedule the user-space process and kernel space thread?

Comment: task_struct controls a single thread (kernel or user space), not a process.

Comment: task_thread controls a single thread means, everything is a thread in user-space and kernel space?   How process and thread differs in user-space?

Comment: Processes and threads in user-space diffen in what they share. Threads share FDs and memory (and a few other things), while processes do not (unless explicitly shared). There is only one kernell memory space, so there is no sense in talking about kernel processes, only kernel threads.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they all handled through `task_struct`.

Critical kernel threads have RT ("Real-Time") scheduler class which have priority over CFS scheduler that is usually used for user-space threads. . Just check your ps:

`# ps ax --format uname,pid,ppid,tty,cmd,cls,pri,rtprio | egrep '(FF|RR)'`

(kernel threads are shown in square brackets)

However, as you can see many kernel threads have TS scheduler. I do not think that there is reason make all kernel threads realtime. For example, you can defer writeback to a disk over emotional scene shown by VLC player.

Comment: Hi, In linux kernel is it possible to run multiple schedulers, like CFS scheduler and RT scheduler?                                                                                             As per my understanding there will be different scheduler policies like RR,FF and any one policy can be used in a system or by the scheduler.      but after executing ps command updated above, I came to know that different policies can be used in a system or by the scheduler then how process priority and scheduler policy is related?

Comment: RT and CFS are scheduler classes which have different implementation. When kernel picks next task it walks over list of classes: (stop -> deadline (SCHED_DEADLINE) -> rt (SCHED_{FIFO,RR}) -> fair (SCHED_{BATCH,OTHER}) -> idle (SCHED_IDLE). See implementation of `pick_next_task()`

Comment: scheduler classes and scheduler policies both means the same.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover I suppose that even POSIX threads which share the memory segments (e.g. heap, global varaibales ) with another threads, are handled by task_struct as well.